# PHP Looping Through Ten, displaying whether Even Or Odd and Writing To a HTML Table.

Tags: php, loops

I'm currently in an introductory course into PHP and I'm having trouble with my current assignment. Its rather simple in logic, but I can't find where my error is.  The abstract is to loop from  one to ten, display whether the number is even or odd, and display these facts in a table. So, row one would be 1 - odd

This is my current Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>1 To 10 Even Odd</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="common.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    th { text-align: center; background-color: #999; }
    th, td ( padding: 0.6em; )
    tr.alt td { background: #ddd }
</style>
```

```
<h3>1 To 10</h3>

<table cellspacing="1" border="1" style="width: 20em; border: 1px solid #999;">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Even Or Odd?</th>
    </tr>   


 <?php


  $max = 10 ;
  $intCounter = 0;


 while ( $intCounter  < $max){

$intCounter++


?>
<tr <?php if ( $intCounter % 2 == 0 ) echo ' class="alt"' ?> >
    <td> <?php echo $intCounter ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo "even" ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr <?php if ( $intCounter % 2 == 1 ) ?> >
    <td> <?php echo $intCounter ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo "odd" ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php

 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This current code is displaying all the numbers twice. So I'll get 1, odd, 1, even.

Thanks for the help in advance! I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

> row one would be 1 - odd

Put this statement `$intCounter++` at the end of `while` loop, otherwise it would print only 9 rows. Also, your second `<tr <?php if ( $intCounter % 2 == 1 ) ?> > ... </tr>` is redundant here.

If you want to start your table with the odd styled row, then change your code in the following way,

```
// your code

$max = 10 ;
$intCounter = 1;

while($intCounter <= $max){

?>
<tr <?php if($intCounter % 2 == 0){ echo ' class="alt"'; } ?>>
    <td> <?php echo $intCounter; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php if($intCounter % 2 == 0){ echo "even"; }else{ echo "odd"; } ?> </td>
</tr>

<?php
    $intCounter++
}

// your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to display nos from 1 to 10, you should do the following modifications:

> 1. Set `$intCounter = 1` instead of `$intCounter = 0`
> 2. Set `while ($intCounter <= $max)` instead of `while ($intCounter < $max)`
> 3. Mention the increment operation `$intCounter++;` just before the loop ends

Try this:

```
<?php if ($intCounter % 2 == 0 ) { ?>
<tr class='alt'>
    <td> <?php echo $intCounter ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo "even" ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $intCounter ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo "odd" ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```